# how to apply PIVOT conditionally in below case

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have following tables and trying to `PIVOT` both parent and child as column headers. In my case "author and books". I am able to PIVOT either author or books at a time but not able to getting both at a time as comma separated with condition ( condition explained below). I have given sample data and output.author1 and author 2 column shows "AVG" of reviews along with color.

r=red &
y=yellow

In the sample output, we can see `color as r & y`. I have applied a condition here. if  an author gets "r" at any time, Then output is always "r" otherwise "y". In my first case author1 gets y & r. so the output gives r. Other case "r" is not getting so "y" is displayed. If no color assigned it should be "NA"

```
user
Aid userName
1   author1
2   author2


books
bid NAME Aid
1    x    1
2    y    1
3    z    2


Location
loc_id Loc_name

1     UK
2     USA
3     Europe


UserAssign

uid Aid bid loc_d color reviews
1    1   1   1     y    12
2    1   2   1     r    14
3    2   3   1     y    11
4    1   1   2     y    10
5    2   3   2     y    112

Expected o/p
--------------------------------------------

Location  author1   x  y  author2       z
Uk        r,13     12 14  y,11         11
USA       y,10     10     y,112       112
```

Comment: @EJEgyed Using AVG in PIVOT

Answer (score 1):

A useful query in the format you are requesting is not possible. When using `PIVOT`, the expected number of columns in the result should always be the same. In the format that you are displaying the data, additional columns would get added if there was a new book or a new author.

The query below will only work with the specified set of books and authors:

```sql
WITH
    users (aid, username)
    AS
        (SELECT 1, 'author1' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 'author2' FROM DUAL),
    books (bid, name, aid)
    AS
        (SELECT 1, 'x', 1 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 'y', 1 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, 'z', 2 FROM DUAL),
    location (loc_id, loc_name)
    AS
        (SELECT 1, 'UK' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 'USA' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, 'Europe' FROM DUAL),
    UserAssign (u_UID,
                Aid,
                bid,
                loc_id,
                color,
                reviews)
    AS
        (SELECT 1, 1, 1, 1, 'y', 12 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 1, 2, 1, 'r', 14 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, 2, 3, 1, 'y', 11 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 4, 1, 1, 2, 'y', 10 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 5, 2, 3, 2, 'y', 112 FROM DUAL)
SELECT l.loc_name, p.*
  FROM (  --authors
          SELECT loc_id,
                 u.username                                  AS colheader,
                 MIN (color) || ',' || AVG (ua1.reviews)     AS avg_reviews
            FROM userassign ua1 JOIN users u ON (ua1.aid = u.aid)
        GROUP BY loc_id, u.username
        UNION ALL
        --books
        SELECT loc_id, b.name, TO_CHAR (ua2.reviews) AS avg_reviews
          FROM userassign ua2 JOIN books b ON (ua2.bid = b.bid))
       PIVOT (MIN (avg_reviews)
             FOR colheader
             IN ('author1' AS author1,
                'x' AS x,
                'y' AS y,
                'author2' AS author2,
                'z' AS z)) p
       JOIN location l ON (p.loc_id = l.loc_id)
ORDER BY l.loc_name;


LOC_NAME       LOC_ID AUTHOR1    X     Y     AUTHOR2    Z
___________ _________ __________ _____ _____ __________ ______
UK                  1 r,13       12    14    y,11       11
USA                 2 y,10       10          y,112      112
```

Comment: You have mentioned that  "When using PIVOT, the expected number of columns in the result should always be the same."  If I show just parent or child ( one at a time), is it possible with all condition which I have mentioned in the question ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "just parent or child". When using `PIVOT`, the number of columns will always be the same when the query is run. If you are expecting the same query to return a different number of columns based on the data, it is not possible.

Comment: meant by "just parent or child" - Showing only  author1 and author2 in IN clause. We can run a query inside IN to display author1 and author 2 ? Also I didnt get an idea how you applied color condition in above query.

Comment: No, a query can not be run inside the `IN` clause of a `PIVOT`. It would cause the number of columns to be dynamic which is not allowed.  For the formatting, you can read more information about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: how the color condition working in your query ?

Comment: is it possible using dynamic query ? so that PIVOT limitation can be avoided ?